# How to get building holes using Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I use Overpass-Turbo with this XML script to download buildings in a given area:

```
<osm-script>
  <union>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="building"/>      
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="building"/>      
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>    
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

The building are well downloaded except those with a hole inside.
Like the following example, these buildings are multipolygon relations (but not tagged building=yes) composed of an outer tagged building=yes and an inner not tagged.

[image]

When I use my Overpass script, I only get the outer.

So, are these building correct? Shouldn't the relation also be tagged as building?

Else does anyone know how to select the relation from its outer building child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is correct and also returns the "holes", i.e. the ways of the relation with role *inner*.

See this [example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/eBy). The result contains [relation 7621](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/7621), the outer [way 23316006](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/23316006) as well as both inner [ways 23316007](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/23316007) and [23316008](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/23316008).

It is also correct that both the relation itself as well as the inner ways don't (and shouldn't) have any building tag. See [multipolygon relations in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:multipolygon) for more information.

You haven't told us which application has problems with the result. It might be possible that this application has no or incomplete support for multipolygon relations.

Edit:
Try the following query:

```
<osm-script>
  <union>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="building"/>      
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="building"/>      
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>    
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="up"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

The only difference to your query is the additional `<recurse type="up"/>` call.

Another edit:
If I understood correctly the first recursion step is modifying the temporary data and thus "breaking" the second recursion step. Try the following query instead:

```
<osm-script>
  <query type="way">
    <has-kv k="building"/>      
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>  
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="up"/>
  </union>
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, the application is my own OSM data loader for ArcGIS, developped in Java. This app manages well multipolygon relations, but in this case ( http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/eWp ), there is no hole selected.

Comment: Right. It seems like an additional upwards recursion step is needed. See if my updated answer fixes your problem.

Comment: OK, I didn't see the difference. So I tried with the recurse up and now, only multipolygon relations containing a building outer and an inner way are selected. The simple building ways aren't. The example: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/flf    I tried but I don't see any solution to select both multipolygon relations and simple building ways.

Comment: Next try, see my updated answers. Now the result contains regular buildings as well as buildings mapped as multipolygons including inner ways. It also just needs a query for ways with the building key, no additional query for relations is needed.

Comment: It works very well, thanks a lot! I didn't know this kind of structure could be done. I completed this query by adding the same with type="relation", without the recurse "up", for the case a relation is building="yes", mulitpolygon="yes" and ways composing it have no tag except outer or inner roles.

Comment: Yes, this wouldn't work with my queries. Maybe you can post your improved query here or as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution if you want to get building ways, multipolygons containing building ways and other inner ways, and multipolygons tagged "building" with their outer and inner ways:

```
<osm-script>
  <query type="way">
    <has-kv k="building"/>      
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>  
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="up"/>
  </union>
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>

  <query type="relation">
    <has-kv k="building"/>      
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>  
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```